# Giving write permissions to www-data for a file within user's home with limited shell access?

Tags: permissions

I have an access to a remote server with `ssh`, but the access is limited: my account there, say `UseR`, can create files in `/tmp` and in its home directory, but not elsewhere; it can call `chmod` without `sudo` on own files, but cannot call `chown`.

In this context, I first wanted to give to Apache's `www-data` user permissions to create files in a subdirectory of `UseR`'s home folder; but no matter what I did, I couldn't - I always got "permission denied". Then, I thought maybe I could just give permissions to a file, so `www-data` can write to it without creating it - I made the below script `permtest.sh` to test this concept, and run it via ssh as `UseR`, and from a php script so it runs as `www-data`; and obtained some logs.

This is the breakdown of involved path elements:

```
755 drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 Apr 28 11:51 /
1777 drwxrwxrwt 7 root root 4096 May 25 11:22 /tmp
755  drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4096 Oct 25  2013 /home
755  drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4096 Apr 29 12:49 /home/users
755  drwxr-xr-x+ 12 no root 4096 Apr 30 17:07 /home/users/GROUP
775  drwxrwxr-x+ 47 UseR group_users 4096 Jun 21 11:20 /home/users/GROUP/UseR
777  drwxrwxrwx+ 3 UseR group_users 4096 Jun 21 11:22 /home/users/GROUP/UseR/tmp
```

I run `permtest.sh 1` first as `UseR` then as `www-data` which initiates files in `/tmp` and `/home/users/GROUP/UseR/tmp`, then run `permtest.sh 2` first as `www-data` then as `UseR`, which tries to append to files; and finally run `permtest.sh 3` as `UseR` to print out the files, whose result is:

```
+ cat /tmp/MYtest_UseR.txt
testing write
testing write again
test www-data append
test UseR append
+ cat /home/users/GROUP/UseR/tmp/MYtest_UseR.txt
testing write
testing write again
test UseR append
+ cat /tmp/MYtest_www-data.txt
testing write
testing write again
test www-data append
test UseR append
+ cat /home/users/GROUP/UseR/tmp/MYtest_www-data.txt
test UseR append
```

So, the things is this: in `/tmp`, both `UseR` and `www-data` can create a file with 777 permissions upon instantiation, to which the other user can append subsequently. But that seems impossible to do in the home folder subdirectory `/home/users/GROUP/UseR/tmp`; if ran as `www-data`, regardless of whether trying to append to `/home/users/GROUP/UseR/tmp/MYtest_UseR.txt` owned by `UseR`, or trying to create `/home/users/GROUP/UseR/tmp/MYtest_UseR.txt` - the command fails with `cannot create ... Permission denied`. Note, this happens with the containing folder `/home/users/GROUP/UseR/tmp` having 777 permissions.

So my questions are these:

- Is there anything in the above information, that would tell me apriori that `www-data` will not be able to create a file in the user folder `/home/users/GROUP/UseR/tmp`? If not, how could I in principle obtain this information (apart from running the script below)?
- What options do I have, as a limited user, to allow write permissions for a file in `/home/users/GROUP/UseR/tmp` to `www-data`, such that it can modify/append data?

`permtest.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

STAGENUM=${1}
MESELF=$(whoami)
if [ "$STAGENUM" = "" ] ; then
  STAGENUM=1
fi

if [ "$STAGENUM" = "1" ] ; then
  for ix in /tmp /home /home/users /home/users/GROUP /home/users/GROUP/UseR /home/users/GROUP/UseR/tmp ; do
    printf '%s ' `stat -c "%a " ${ix} 2>&1`
    ls -lad ${ix} 2>&1
  done

  set -x
  for ix in /tmp /home/users/GROUP/UseR/tmp ; do
    touch ${ix}/MYtest_${MESELF}.txt 2>&1
    chmod 777 ${ix}/MYtest_${MESELF}.txt 2>&1
    ls -la ${ix}/MYtest_${MESELF}.txt 2>&1
    echo "testing write" > ${ix}/MYtest_${MESELF}.txt 2>&1
    echo "testing write again" | tee -a ${ix}/MYtest_${MESELF}.txt 2>&1
    cat ${ix}/MYtest_${MESELF}.txt 2>&1
    echo rm ${ix}/MYtest_${MESELF}.txt 2>&1 # don't remove now
  done
fi

if [ "$STAGENUM" = "2" ] ; then
  set -x
  echo "test $MESELF append" >> '/tmp/MYtest_UseR.txt' 2>&1
  echo "test $MESELF append" >> '/home/users/GROUP/UseR/tmp/MYtest_UseR.txt' 2>&1
  echo "test $MESELF append" >> '/tmp/MYtest_www-data.txt' 2>&1
  echo "test $MESELF append" >> '/home/users/GROUP/UseR/tmp/MYtest_www-data.txt' 2>&1
  set +x
  ls -la '/tmp/MYtest_UseR.txt' 2>&1
  ls -la '/home/users/GROUP/UseR/tmp/MYtest_UseR.txt' 2>&1
  ls -la '/tmp/MYtest_www-data.txt' 2>&1
  ls -la '/home/users/GROUP/UseR/tmp/MYtest_www-data.txt' 2>&1
fi

if [ "$STAGENUM" = "3" ] ; then
  set -x
  cat '/tmp/MYtest_UseR.txt' 2>&1
  cat '/home/users/GROUP/UseR/tmp/MYtest_UseR.txt' 2>&1
  cat '/tmp/MYtest_www-data.txt' 2>&1
  cat '/home/users/GROUP/UseR/tmp/MYtest_www-data.txt' 2>&1
  set +x
fi

if [ "$STAGENUM" = "4" ] ; then
  rm '/tmp/MYtest_UseR.txt' 2>&1 ;
  rm '/home/users/GROUP/UseR/tmp/MYtest_UseR.txt' 2>&1 ;
  rm '/tmp/MYtest_www-data.txt' 2>&1 ;
  rm '/home/users/GROUP/UseR/tmp/MYtest_www-data.txt' 2>&1
fi
```

Comment: Could you give some background on what you are trying to do? E.g. why you want "to give to Apache's www-data user permissions to create files in a subdirectory of UseR's home folder".

Comment: Thanks @FaheemMitha - trying to set up HTTP access to bare `git` repos in my home directory there, which works fine, except for push, because in that case `git-http-backend` runs as `www-data`, and fails to update the bare repos; cheers!

Comment: There are standard ways of allowing web access to a git repos. And if not, checking it out in the space the web server is normally given read access to seems a more normal thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ls output shows with a **+** sign in the modes that your files and directories are using ACLs.

```
drwxr-xr-x+ ...
```

These may be restricting your accesses. List the acl permissions with

```
getfacl <file or directory>
```

and remove them with

```
setfacl -b <file or directory>
```

then check again.

---

EDIT from OP: Indeed, that is it - here is a snippet of what I did in the ssh shell (first copying permissions from elsewhere on one file, then giving extra permissions to `www-data` on the other file) - and afterwards `www-data` could append fine to these files:

```
UseR:~/tmp$ getfacl MYtest_www-data.txt
# file: MYtest_www-data.txt
# owner: UseR
# group: group_users
user::rw-
user:www-data:r-x       #effective:r--
group::r-x          #effective:r--
group:www-data:r-x      #effective:r--
mask::r--
other::r--

UseR:~/tmp$ getfacl /tmp/MYtest_www-data.txt
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: tmp/MYtest_www-data.txt
# owner: www-data
# group: www-data
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx

UseR:~/tmp$ getfacl /tmp/MYtest_www-data.txt | setfacl --set-file=- MYtest_www-data.txt
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
UseR:~/tmp$ getfacl MYtest_www-data.txt
# file: MYtest_www-data.txt
# owner: UseR
# group: group_users
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx

UseR:~/tmp$ ls -la MYtest_www-data.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 UseR group_users 22 Jun 21 12:44 MYtest_www-data.txt

$ getfacl MYtest_UseR.txt
# file: MYtest_UseR.txt
# owner: UseR
# group: group_users
user::rwx
user:www-data:r-x
group::r-x
group:www-data:r-x
mask::rwx
other::rwx

UseR:~/tmp$ setfacl -m u:www-data:w MYtest_UseR.txt
UseR:~/tmp$ getfacl MYtest_UseR.txt
# file: MYtest_UseR.txt
# owner: UseR
# group: group_users
user::rwx
user:www-data:-w-
group::r-x
group:www-data:r-x
mask::rwx
other::rwx

UseR:~/tmp$ setfacl -m u:www-data:rw MYtest_UseR.txt
UseR:~/tmp$ getfacl MYtest_UseR.txt
# file: MYtest_UseR.txt
# owner: UseR
# group: group_users
user::rwx
user:www-data:rw-
group::r-x
group:www-data:r-x
mask::rwx
other::rwx
```

Comment: Many thanks @meuh - indeed, that was it; edited your post with a snippet of server operations, hope it passes peer review; cheers!